# App Engine (Java) Blobstore: no BlobInfo after successfully storing blob

Tags: java, google-app-engine, blobstore, datastore

From the documentation of the App Engine Blobstore, there should be a BlobInfo entry in the DataStore for each entry in the BlobStore. Then why is my blobInfo null in the code below?

Note:

- If I remove the BlobInfo code, the servlet returns the resource as it should (but without a filename)
- For brevity, I removed exception and parameter handling

I would be very grateful for your help.

```
public class GetResourceServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private BlobstoreService blobstoreService = BlobstoreServiceFactory.getBlobstoreService();
    private BlobInfoFactory infoFactory = new BlobInfoFactory();

    public void doGet (  HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
             throws ServletException, IOException {

       String blobKeyStr = request.getParameter("blob-key");
       BlobKey blobKey = new BlobKey(blobKeyStr);

       BlobInfo info = infoFactory.loadBlobInfo(blobKey); // returns null !?
       String fname = info.getFilename();
       response.addHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fname);

       blobstoreService.serve(blobKey, response);
    }
```

Comment: Can you see the blob you're trying to access in the BlobViewer in the admin console?

Comment: The blob exists in the Blobstore. In fact, the blobstoreService.serve() returns the blob as it should. The problem is that I cannot retrieve the blob's metadata that should be stored in the Datastore (not Blobstore). If I look in the DataViewer, I cannot see any entries of type 'BlobInfo', but I don't know if I should...

Comment: The metadata is stored under __BlobInfo__. Query with "SELECT * FROM __BlobInfo__"

Comment: Thanks for your help Stuart. Unfortunately, the query returns no results. What am I overlooking? Do I need to do something before the blobs are put into the BlobStore?

Comment: for some reason stack overflow removed the '__' from the from the front and back of BlobInfo. The BlobInfo you want to query for has two underscored at the before and after BlobInfo.

Comment: Thanks, now I can see the __BlobInfo__ items. So now I have proof the BlobInfo instance exists, its key corresponds with the key of the blob in BlobStore. Still, the code above does not return the BlobInfo item.

Comment: Stuart, I tried to fetch the __BlobInfo__ item directly from the datastore, using datastore.get(key), where key = KeyFactory.createkey("__BlobInfo__", blobKeyStr). I get Entity not found error. But from the admin page I see the item is there and that the key is correct.

Comment: I am running from a different version (called "dev") than the version that I used to upload the blob (called "1"). Could that be the problem? It shouldn't, but I am really clueless

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found the problem. The key string (blobKeyStr) contained a newline character at the end. The nasty thing is that you don't notice it in logging. Adding a `blobKeyStr = blobKeyStr.trim()` solved the problem

Comment: So with your code, you can get the content of the file? because I need it to upload on Google Cloud Storage

Comment: Yes, the blobStoreService.serve instructs Google App Engine to get the content and send it to the client. In this case the client should get these contents as a file download. That's why I needed the BlobInfo to get a filename.

Comment: Ok thanks :-) So that is the DownloadSide. Have you got problems during Upload? Because i'm getting Error when i try to upload files greater than 32MB and i don't know how to fix it. Does your code work with it? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do the following first:

- ensure that the blob is present in the local data store by visiting 'http://local host:8080/_ah/admin' and then data store viewer. You should see new entries Hcreated for your blobs. Note down the key values.
- make sure that you are using the correct blob key in your request.

You mentione that you have removed exception handling code from above due to brevity. Do you get any exceptions while ying to retrieve the blob that supposedly does not exist?

Comment: I will get an exception on info.getFilename(), because info==null. If I remove this line, the servlet will return the resource as it should (However, the client doesn't get a filename or a filetype.) So the Blob is there and the blobkey is fine. Why is there no blobinfo data in the Datastore? I assume it is created and stored automatically when the blob is stored, right?